# What is the minimum scope set when using GitHub API to support listing private repositories and using the status API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-organizations

My scenario is that I would like to list the private repositories for the user, given the organizations they grant access to. The intent is to provide status API integration.

I use the `user:email` scope as a form of identification in my app, so I am requesting that along with `repo` and `read:org`.  I was trying to use `repo:status` instead of `repo`, but I couldn't seem to get the private repo listing that way.

So, my final set of scopes is:

```
user:email
repo
read:org
```

Is this the minimum set of scopes required, or am I missing a more restrictive combination that would work without write access to repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scopes are almost correct. You don't need the `read:org` scope to list organisations if you have `repo`.

Somewhat annoyingly, there is no scope to grant read only access to a *private* repo, even though there are separate read and write scopes for public ones. You can't read private repos without also allowing writing via the `repo` scope.

You're also right about `repo:status`—this scope is meant for interacting with commit statuses without being able to see the contents of the repository, for example a CI service like Travis.

Comment: Thanks! Seems as though listing repos shouldn't be something that requires carrying a write permission.  :o/